# How to I compare an input value to reference values in an object literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object-literal

I'd like to compare a user input value, to a set of values arranged in an object literal. The user will input two values, a reference variable `wk` and a `number`. Those need to be cross referenced in the object literal, but I can't seem to figure out the logic to do so?

The object literal is constructed as follows:

```
var reference = {
   wk31: {
        _90th: '758',
        _75th: '683',
        _50th: '600',
        _25th: '516',
        _10th: '441'
    },
    wk32: {
        _90th: '815',
        _75th: '734',
        _50th: '644',
        _25th: '554',
        _10th: '472'
    },
    wk33: {
        _90th: '870',
        _75th: '783',
        _50th: '687',
        _25th: '590',
        _10th: '503'
    }
}
```

For example, if 
`wk = 32` & `number = 755`, then I'd like to make the user aware that their `number is between the 75th and 90th percentile for that wk value`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a request, or a question?  What have you tried thus far?

Comment: You need to first select the object `wk##` with the user input and then iterate the Object's keys.

Comment: Also the code in the example contains no javascript arrays, only object literals.

Comment: Honestly,  haven't tried anything specific, because I'm not sure how to take each variable and iterate between the upper and lower value limits?. I can find a specific value tied to an array key, but only when I know what I'm looking for in the array. When the item is a variable, I'm not sure how the iteration argument works.

Comment: @danludwig - you are right, I will update the question to be more specific that these are object literals in a larger piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what is written [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), it appears you cannot rely on the order of the array returned by `Object.keys()` and the order in which the `for ... in` loop will enumerate over an object's properties.

Instead, rearrange the data into something that is more usable.

First, get the correct object for the `wk` value using the following:

```
var wkObj = reference['wk' + wk];
```

Then rearrange those values using:

```
var percentiles = $.map(wkObj, function(value, key) {
    return { number: Number(value), percentile: key.substr(1) };
}).sort(function(a, b) { return a.number - b.number; });
```

This creates an array of objects, where each object has two properties: (1) `number`, which is a number, and (2) `percentile`, which is a string. The array is sorted by the `number` values in ascending order.

For example, the `percentiles` array would look like the following for `wk = 32`:

```
[
    { number: 472, percentile: '10th' },
    { number: 554, percentile: '25th' },
    { number: 644, percentile: '50th' },
    { number: 734, percentile: '75th' },
    { number: 815, percentile: '90th' }
]
```

Now the `number` values are numbers, not strings, and you can safely loop through the array in the desired order.

```
var upperIndex = -1;
$.each(percentiles, function(i, obj) {
    if (obj.number > number) {
        upperIndex = i;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkapaum0/) that shows the code above in use.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what  was looking for - a result that returns the upper and lower percentiles for a given `number` and `wk` combination. What if I just readjusted the syntax of my object in the manner you suggested, then I wouldn't need to programmatically change it?

Comment: @user1837608 - Yes, if you alter the format of the data, you could save that step in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var reference = {
    wk31: {
   _90th: '758',
   _75th: '683',
   _50th: '600',
   _25th: '516',
   _10th: '441'
  },
  wk32: {
   _90th: '815',
   _75th: '734',
   _50th: '644',
   _25th: '554',
   _10th: '472'
  },
  wk33: {
   _90th: '870',
   _75th: '783',
   _50th: '687',
   _25th: '590',
   _10th: '503'
  }
 }

 function checkReference()
 {
  var input = "wk" + document.querySelector("#week_input").value;
  var perc = document.querySelector("#numberInput").value;
  
  var obj = reference[input];
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  
  var string = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
  {
   if (perc > obj[keys[i]])
   {
    if (i == 0)
    {
     string = "number higher than 90th percentile for that wk value.";
     break;
    }
    else
    {
     string = "number is between "+keys[i].substr(1)+" and "+ keys[i-1].substr(1) +" percentile for that wk value.";
     break;
    }
   }
   else if (perc < obj[keys[i]] && i == keys.length-1)
   {
    string = "number lower than 10th percentile for that wk value.";
   }
  }
  
  alert(string);
 }
 document.querySelector("#doCheck").addEventListener("click", checkReference, false);
```

```html
<input id="week_input" type="range" min="31" max="33">
<input id="numberInput" type="range" min="0" max="1000"><br />
<button id="doCheck">Check</button>
```

Something like this:

User slides the values into place. The code checks the object and returns the value. The sliders are used to greatly reduce user input errors.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS

```
var reference = {
   wk31: {
        _90th: '758',
        _75th: '683',
        _50th: '600',
        _25th: '516',
        _10th: '441'
    },
    wk32: {
        _90th: '815',
        _75th: '734',
        _50th: '644',
        _25th: '554',
        _10th: '472'
    },
    wk33: {
        _90th: '870',
        _75th: '783',
        _50th: '687',
        _25th: '590',
        _10th: '503'
    }
}

var result = $("#result");
//wk value
var bracket = 32;
//value to factor into percentile
var value = 740;
var percentileResult = "";

for (var i in reference) {
    if (reference.hasOwnProperty(i) && i.indexOf("wk" + bracket) !== -1) {
        var ref = reference[i];
        for (var j in ref) {
            if (ref.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                var percentileValue = ref[j];
                if (percentileValue < value) {
                    percentileResult = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }    
    }
};

result.html(value + " is in the " + percentileResult.replace("_", "") + " percentile of wk" + bracket);
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7avjhvsy/

Consider adding the following code snippets before the loop and inside the first loop's if statement respectively if you might have wk values such as wk31 and wk311.  In which case the second condition would evaluate to true for both and pick up an incorrect value:

```
regex = new RegExp("wk(/\d{" + bracket.toString().length + "})", "g");

if (reference.hasOwnProperty(i) && i.indexOf("wk" + bracket) !== -1 && regex.test(i)) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts. It's pretty close to what I need for my application - except that I need to let my users know the percentile range that their `number` value falls in. So, `number = 744` would yield a result stating that it is **between** the 75th and 90th percentile.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
        function findUpperPercentile(wk, number, reference){    
              var upperPercentile = "_100th"; 
              var wkArray = reference['wk'+wk];
              for (var i in wkArray ){
                  if (wkArray[i]>number){
                      upperPercentile=i
                  }
              } 
              return upperPercentile;
         }
```

Comment: A result that should be in the OPs top 4 percentiles will always equal the 5th index with this.